# Can't open UE5 project on Windows

Tags: unreal

I created a UE5 project on macOS and I'm now trying to open it on a Windows 10 machine.

I made sure not to copy the Saved, Binaries, DerivedDataCache and Intermediate folders, but when I try to open it I get the following errors at build time:

```
Log file open, 07/12/21 08:01:13
LogWindows: Failed to load 'aqProf.dll' (GetLastError=126)
LogWindows: File 'aqProf.dll' does not exist
LogProfilingDebugging: Loading WinPixEventRuntime.dll for PIX profiling (from ../../../Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Windows/WinPixEventRuntime/x64).
LogWindows: Failed to load 'VtuneApi.dll' (GetLastError=126)
LogWindows: File 'VtuneApi.dll' does not exist
LogWindows: Failed to load 'VtuneApi32e.dll' (GetLastError=126)
LogWindows: File 'VtuneApi32e.dll' does not exist
LogConsoleResponse: Display: Failed to find resolution value strings in scalability ini. Falling back to default.
LogConsoleResponse: Display: Failed to find resolution value strings in scalability ini. Falling back to default.
LogInit: Display: Running engine for game: MyProject2
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper
LogStats: Stats thread started at 12.742427
LogD3D11RHI: Loaded GFSDK_Aftermath_Lib.x64.dll
LogICUInternationalization: ICU TimeZone Detection - Raw Offset: +1:00, Platform Override: ''
LogConfig: Display: Loading platform ini files took 0.29 seconds
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MeshPainting
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin XGEController
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Bridge
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AISupport
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin EnvironmentQueryEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CameraShakePreviewer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Paper2D
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GameplayCameras
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LuminPlatformFeatures
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapLightEstimation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MLSDK
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AnimationSharing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeap
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapPassableWorld
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CLionSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CodeLiteSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin KDevelopSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GitSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin NullSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlasticSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PerforceSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PluginUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PropertyAccessNode
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin RiderSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SubversionSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VisualStudioSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UObjectPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TcpMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UdpMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VisualStudioCodeSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin XCodeSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AvfMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Niagara
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ImgMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MediaCompositing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WmfMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MediaPlayerEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WebMMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin DatasmithContent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AssetManagerEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VariantManagerContent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CryptoKeys
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CurveEditorTools
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin DataValidation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin EditorDebugTools
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin FacialAnimation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GameplayTagsEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryMode
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin InterchangeEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MacGraphicsSwitching
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MaterialAnalyzer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobileLauncherProfileWizard
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LauncherChunkInstaller
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SpeedTreeImporter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin EditorScriptingUtilities
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AutomationUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin BackChannel
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PluginBrowser
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AlembicImporter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosCloth
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosClothEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosSolverPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CharacterAI
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryCache
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryCollectionPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryProcessing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MeshModelingToolset
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ProxyLODPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlanarCut
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlatformCrypto
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SkeletalReduction
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosNiagara
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystem
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemNull
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ActorSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LevelSequenceEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MatineeToLevelSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TemplateSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MotoSynth
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ActorLayerUtilities
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidPermission
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ArchVisCharacter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AssetTags
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AudioCapture
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AppleImageUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AppleMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AudioSynesthesia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CableComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChunkDownloader
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ExampleDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CustomMeshComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GoogleCloudMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GooglePAD
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ScreenshotTools
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MultiUserTakes
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Interchange
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Takes
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin IOSDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LinuxDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LocationServicesBPLibrary
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobilePatchingUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ProceduralMeshComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PropertyAccessEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin RuntimePhysXCooking
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SoundFields
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SignificanceManager
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WebMMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WindowsMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Synthesis
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin HairStrands
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ConcertMain
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MultiUserClient
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ContentBrowserAssetDataSource
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ContentBrowserClassDataSource
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemIOS
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SQLiteCore
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OculusVR
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SteamVR
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ConcertSyncClient
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ConcertSyncCore
LogInit: Warning: Incompatible or missing module: MyProject2
Running F:/Programmi/UE_5.0EA/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="F:/unnamed-zombie-game/MyProject2.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
ERROR: Could not find NetFxSDK install dir; this will prevent SwarmInterface from installing.  Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher.
LogInit: Warning: Still incompatible or missing module: MyProject2
LogCore: Engine exit requested (reason: EngineExit() was called)
LogExit: Preparing to exit.
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module DesktopPlatform (48)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCryptoOpenSSL (46)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCryptoTypes (44)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCrypto (42)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module XGEController (40)
LogXGEController: Cannot use XGE Controller as Incredibuild is not installed on this machine.
LogXGEController: Cleaning working directory: C:/Users/Ale/AppData/Local/Temp/UnrealXGEWorkingDir/
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimationModifiers (38)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AudioEditor (36)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PropertyEditor (35)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module TextureCompressor (32)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module RenderCore (30)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Landscape (28)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SlateRHIRenderer (26)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module OpenGLDrv (24)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module D3D11RHI (22)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimGraphRuntime (20)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Renderer (18)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Engine (16)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CoreUObject (14)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module NetworkFile (12)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CookedIterativeFile (10)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module StreamingFile (8)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SandboxFile (6)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PakFile (4)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module RSA (3)
LogExit: Exiting.
Log file closed, 07/12/21 08:04:47
```

In addition to Epic Games Launcher and UE5 I also installed Visual Studio 2019 and dotnet-sdk-5.0.301-win-x64.

The very same project compiles just fine on my macOS machine if I delete the above folders so I'd exclude a problem with the project itself.

May someone help me figure out what's missing?

Comment: The problem appears to be here: `ERROR: Could not find NetFxSDK install dir; this will prevent SwarmInterface from installing.  Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher`

Comment: Thanks but I already installed the version 5.0.301, isn't it okay? Do I need a 4.x version?

Comment: No idea. I just wanted to point out the actual error in your log so others have less work digging through all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have .NET Core 3.1 installed.

You might need a version of 4 as well. Easiest way is to install through the Visual Studio installer.

You can do that through Visual Studio installer or get it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.1.409-windows-x64-installer)